# R More detailed progress bars in for loops

Tags: r, for-loop, time, progress-bar

I'm playing with a progress bar for some of my loops.

Outside of the loop I've written:

```
total = length(df$x)

pb <- winProgressBar(title = "Progress Bar", min = 0, max =total , width = 300)
```

Then before closing the loop I have:

```
setWinProgressBar(pb, i, title=paste( round(which(df$x== i)/total*100, 0),"% done"))
```

This gives me a progress bar that does update the %. However the bar doesn't fill up at all. I would like the bar space to fill (preferably blue if we have a choice). What do I need to add? I would also like a time remaining element added, like in pbapply.

On another, more complicated note, of course one shortfalls is that each i may not be equal in size/length and thus the progress bar in theory doesn't tell you everything you need to know about time that may be taken.

Is there any way to build within my loop such that we scan all i first and then the progress bar works off of that distribution rather than assuming it's uniform? In the loops I'm using at the minute, each i is a file that is converted into a data.frame. File size or length of rows in the data frame would be good measures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self taught answer for getting the bar to fill. Example with loop that reads files:

```
df <- data.frame(x=(list.files("new/")))
total = length(df$x)

pb <- winProgressBar(title = "Progress Bar", label="0% done", min = 0, max =total , width = 300, initial=0)


for(i in df$x){
         u <- fread(paste0("Z:/sec/new/",i))

setWinProgressBar(pb, which(df$x== i),label=paste( round(which(df$x== i)/total*100, 0),"% done"))
    }

close(pb)
```

The time and scanning file sizes first I've yet to figure out.